# How to create a TS type which has enum value as key and corresponding React functional component as value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Please see the code block below.

```
import Button from './Button'; // React component which has type React.FC<ButtonType>
import Select from './Select'; // React component which has type React.FC<SelectType>
import Checkbox from './Checkbox'; // React component which has type React.FC<CheckboxType>

enum ComponentType {
  button = 'bla_button',
  select = 'bla_select',
  checkbox = 'bla_checkbox',
}

type ComponentMap = {
  [key in ComponentType]: React.FC<any>;
};

const componentMap: ComponentMap = {
  [ComponentType.button]: Button,
  [ComponentType.select]: Select,
  [ComponentType.checkbox]: Checkbox,
};
```

I want to have a better type for `ComponentMap` instead of using `React.FC<any>` so it can infer when the key is `'bla_button'`, the value must be `Button` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to an interface/type which specifies the relational mapping from string key to function component value. You can use the [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) keyword to extract the type from the FC imports, and use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```js
type MapEnumToComponent = {
    'bla_button': typeof Button;
    'bla_select': typeof Select;
    'bla_checkbox': typeof Checkbox;
}

type ComponentMap = {
  [key in ComponentType]: MapEnumToComponent[key];
};
```

View this on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkOzPW)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, it was so helpful for me.